# How long should I run Hamiltonian simulation to roll a six-sided dice?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, applications

### Introduction and Motivation

Aharanov has [hinted](https://medium.com/qiskit/why-this-quantum-pioneer-thinks-we-need-more-people-working-on-quantum-algorithms-3020729c61e1), and perhaps Aaronson has also recently [echoed](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6457), that there may be many quantum algorithms to be discovered if more computer scientists were familiar with various problems and concepts in physics.  To that end I've been considering some toy problems and asking what concepts in (quantum) physics may apply.

One toy that I've been thinking about recently is that of rolling six-sided dice, in such a way that the top face is uniformly distributed among the six different faces with one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ [pips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(counting)).

Below I'll describe a classical approach to simulating the rolling of a die, along with the data registers used; then I'll ponder the same but with a quantum algorithm.  I'll ask the main question at the end.

---

### Data Structure with Classical Simulation

Initially for a classical approach one might:

- Start by labeling registers of the die in some canonical fashion, such as in a perspective view with the six registers for the top $\mathrm{T}$, bottom $\mathrm{B}$, left $\mathrm{L}$, right $\mathrm{R}$, port $\mathrm{P}$ (the back left), and starboard $\mathrm{S}$ (the back right);
- Initialize and orient the die in some predetermined initialization, such as with a single pip "$1$" on the top face $\mathrm{T}$, the faces with "$2$" and "$3$" pips to the left $\mathrm{L}$ and right $\mathrm{R}$ (and "$6$", "$5$", and "$4$" on the faces $\mathrm{B},\mathrm{S},\mathrm{P}$);
- Choose a sequence of $t\in\mathbb{N}$ random rotations $\{T,B,L,R,P,S\}$ to rotate the die clockwise by a quarter-turn around the respective six faces; and
- After the $t^{\mathrm{th}}$ rotation, note the number of pips shown on the top face $\mathrm{T}$ as the answer to the roll.

My guess is that as long as $t\ge 6$ or so, the roll would be uniformly drawn from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  This perhaps simulates the physics of rolling a die on a table - the die tumbles and twists to the right or left or forward or backward...

[image: Dice Rolls]

Indeed, we can envision six registers (one for each face), each recording the pip count as an integer from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and we can describe classical reversible circuits as above.  The unitalicized registers are $\{\mathrm{T},\mathrm{B},\mathrm{L},\mathrm{S},\mathrm{R},\mathrm{P}\}$ while the italicized quarter-turn operators are $\{T,B,L,S,R,P\}.$

---

### Quantum Algorithm

To make a quantum version of the same, I envision six registers of six-dimensional qudits initialized in the same manner.  Quantumly (and not classically), **we can take the $n$th root of each quarter-turn rotation**.  By cycling through the six rotations in sequence, and repeating this $n$ times as in the [Lie product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula) with a Trotter factor of $n$, we can simulate a Hamiltonian for the rolling of the die.

I believe this corresponds to one single time step ($t=1$) in the Hamiltonian evolution of the rolling of the dice.  Each operator acts on four qudits; thus this is a $4$-local, $6$-dimensional Hamiltonian.

For example, our state is initialized as:

$$|\psi\rangle=|\mathrm{TBLSRP}\rangle=|162543\rangle,$$

and a single time step of the evolution, with a Trotter factor of $4$, is:

$$W|\psi\rangle:=(\sqrt[4] T\sqrt[4] B\sqrt[4] L\sqrt[4] S\sqrt[4] R\sqrt[4] P)^4|\psi\rangle.$$

Here as opposed to the classical case, there is no randomness in the algorithm itself; the randomness is instead inherent in performing a projective measurement on the resultant wavefunction.

Nonetheless I don't know how long an evolution would be needed, or if it's even possible, to have the top register $\mathrm{T}$ be uniformly distributed over each of the six faces - surely six steps would suffice?

> **If we were to evolve the Hamiltonian by repeating the above product formula $W$ for $t=6$ times, acting on the initial state $W^6|\psi\rangle$, and then trace out the top register $|\mathrm{T}\rangle$, would it also be uniformly distributed among the six different faces?**

With six faces and six dimensions per face, this is outside what can be easily simulated with [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk), but is the guess of $t=6$ reasonable?  Indeed, what would happen for even longer - say, $t=100$ or so?

---

<sup>I know that this is a trivial problem insofar as no one would use a quantum computer in this manner, but nonetheless it seems to be interesting to me to study.  Also I think, but haven't yet proven, that the classical algorithm describes a $t$-length classical random walk on the adjacency matrix of the Cayley graph of the group of rotational symmetries of a cube, with the six specific generators, and that this is isomorphic to $S_n$ but mod'ed out by the orientation of the pips.</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by "top face is uniformly distributed among the six different faces with one of {1,2,3,4,5,6}"? This sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: I’ll edit it for clarity later but I mean that if you trace out the top register $\mathrm T$ then the squared amplitudes of each basis state $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is 1/6 or nearly so. We can trivially prepare a qudit (d=6) in a uniform superposition with a 6-dimensional version of a Hadamard gate, but here I’m asking about starting with six qudits as faces on a die and quantumly “rolling” the die with Hamiltonian simulation. I only need to trace out the top face and am asking how long it takes to “roll” the die.